# Content management system for teaching PHP OOP to beginners

Tags: php, object-oriented

I created this basic content management system to teach object oriented PHP to beginners. However, I am concerned that it violates SOLID principles in App.php and Router.php.

[Here's the project on GitHub](https://github.com/mtkocak/merakli)

App.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * The class that starts our application.
 *
 * Works as dependency injector.
 * TODO Have to check solid principle violations.
 * TODO Have to convert the class to static and use registry pattern for instantiated classes
 *
 * @author   Midori Kocak <mtkocak@mtkocak.net>
 */
namespace Midori\Cms;

use Midori\Cms;
use erbilen;

/**
 * Class App
 *
 * @package Midori\Cms
 *         
 */
class App
{

    /**
     * Holds application wide settings
     *
     * @var mixed
     */
    protected $settings = false;

    /**
     * The variable that holds database connection.
     *
     * @var mixed
     */
    private $db = false;

    /**
     * Holds request params, coming from uri.
     *
     * @var mixed
     */
    private $params = array();

    /**
     * Extracted params for request generation
     *
     * @var array
     */
    private $request;

    /**
     * The data that comes from forms or classes
     *
     * @var mixed
     */
    private $data = null;

    /**
     * Function that starts application using config vars
     *
     * @param
     *            $config
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function __construct($config)
    {
        $this->startSession();
        $this->getRequests();
        $this->startDB($config);

        $this->params = explode("/", $this->request);

        $params = $this->params;

        $className = __NAMESPACE__ . '\\' . $this->params[1];

        $class = new $className($this->db);
        $class->getRelatedData($this->getCategories());

        if (empty($this->data)) {
            if (! isset($params[2]) || ! $params[2]) {
                $this->params[2] = 'index';
            } else {
                if (isset($params[3])) {
                    $this->data = $class->$params[2]($params[3]);
                } else {
                    $this->data = $class->$params[2]();
                }
            }
        } else {
            $this->data = call_user_func_array(array(
                $class,
                $params[2]
            ), $this->data);
            header('Location:' . LINK_PREFIX . '/'.$this->params[1].'/show');
        }

        try {
            $this->startDB($config);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            if ($e->getCode() == 1049) {
                $this->startDatabaseInstaller();
            }
        }

        if ($this->getUsers() == false) {
            $this->startUserInstaller();
        } elseif (! $this->getSettings()) {
            $this->startSettingInstaller();
        } else {
            $this->startCategoryAndPostInstaller();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Session starter function for the whole app
     *
     * @return null
     */
    public function startSession()
    {
        $session_name = session_name();
        if (session_start()) {
            setcookie($session_name, session_id(), null, '/', null, null, true);
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Requests are handled by this method
     *
     * @return null
     */
    public function getRequests()
    {
        if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) !== false) {
            $request = str_replace($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], "", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        } else {
            $requests = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

            if ($requests[1] == DIRECTORY_NAME) {
                unset($requests[1]);

                $request = implode('/', $requests);

                if ($request == "/") {
                    $request .= "posts";
                }
            }
        }
        if (! empty($_POST)) {
            $this->data = $_POST;
        } elseif (! empty($_FILES)) {
            $this->data = $_FILES;
        } else {
            $this->data = "";
        }
        if (empty($request)) {
            $this->request = "/Posts/";
        }
        $this->request = $request;
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Instantiates database connection
     * TODO has to be static.
     *
     * @param
     *            $config
     * @return null
     */
    public function startDB($config)
    {
        $db = new erbilen\BasicDB($config['db']['host'], $config['db']['dbname'], $config['db']['username'], $config['db']['password']);
        $this->getDb($db);
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Method starts database connection
     *
     * @param BasicDBObject $dbConnection            
     * @return BasicDB object or False.
     */
    public function getDb($dbConnection)
    {
        if (! $dbConnection) {
            return false;
        } else {
            $this->db = $dbConnection;
            return $this->db;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Categories are shown everywhere.
     * So we need to get them to an array.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCategories()
    {
        $categories = new Categories($this->db);
        return $categories->index();
    }

    /**
     * Database creation form is handled here.
     *
     * @return null
     */
    public function startDatabaseInstaller()
    {
        if (isset($_POST['db']['host'])) {
            $_POST['db']['host'] = filter_var(gethostbyname($_POST['db']['host']), FILTER_VALIDATE_IP);
        }

        if (isset($_POST['db']['dbname']) && preg_match('/^\w{5,}$/', $_POST['db']['dbname'])) {
            $_POST['db']['dbname'] = filter_var($_POST['db']['dbname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES);
        }

        if (isset($_POST['db']['username']) && preg_match('/^\w{5,}$/', $_POST['db']['username'])) {
            $_POST['db']['username'] = filter_var($_POST['db']['username'], FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES);
        }

        if (isset($_POST['db']['password'])) {
            $_POST['db']['password'] = filter_var($_POST['db']['password'], FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES);
        }
        if (isset($_POST['db'])) {
            $config['db'] = $_POST['db'];
            echo $this->installDatabase($config);
        } else {
            echo $this->installDatabase();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method for installing database config to config.php
     *
     * @param null $config            
     * @return null;
     */
    public function installDatabase($config = null)
    {
        $comments = "";
        $tokens = token_get_all(file_get_contents('./Config/config.inc.php'));
        foreach ($tokens as $token) {
            if ($token[0] == T_COMMENT || $token[0] == T_DOC_COMMENT) {
                $comments .= $token[1] . "\n";
            }
        }

        if ($config != null) {
            file_put_contents('./Config/config.inc.php', '<?php' . "\n" . $comments . "\n" . '$config = ' . var_export($config, true) . ';');
            header('Location:' . LINK_PREFIX);
        } else {
            return $this->render('./View/Install/database.php', '');
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Renders file and variables
     *
     * @param
     *            $file
     * @param
     *            $vars
     * @return null
     */
    public function render($file, $vars)
    {
        $renderer = new Router();
        echo $renderer->render($file, $vars);
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Method to check system has any registered user
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getUsers()
    {
        $user = $this->db->select('users')->run();
        if (! $user) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * If the application has no user registered, visitor is forced to create an user.
     */
    public function startUserInstaller()
    {
        if (! isset($_POST['user'])) {
            echo $this->installUser();
        } else {
            if (isset($_POST['user']['username']) && preg_match('/^\w{5,}$/', $_POST['user']['username']) && filter_var($_POST['user']['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                $_POST['user']['username'] = filter_var($_POST['user']['username'], FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES);

                if (isset($_POST['user']['password1']) && isset($_POST['user']['password2']) && ($_POST['user']['password1'] == $_POST['user']['password2'])) {
                    echo $this->installUser($_POST['user']);
                } else {
                    echo $this->installUser();
                }
            } else {
                echo $this->installUser();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handles user registration form.
     *
     * @param null $userInfo            
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function installUser($userInfo = null)
    {
        if ($userInfo == null) {
            return $this->render('./View/Install/user.php', '');
        } else {
            $insert = $this->db->insert('users')->set(array(
                "username" => $userInfo['username'],
                "password" => md5($userInfo['password1']),
                "email" => $userInfo['email']
            ));

            if ($insert) {
                header('Location:' . LINK_PREFIX);
            } else {
                return $this->render('./View/Install/user.php', '');
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Basic settings are also needed everywhere.
     *
     * @return bool.
     */
    public function getSettings()
    {
        $settings = new Settings($this->db);
        $setting = $settings->view();
        $this->settings = $setting['setting'];
        if ($this->settings != null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * If the application has no settings created, visitor is forced to create the setting.
     */
    public function startSettingInstaller()
    {
        if (isset($_POST['setting'])) {
            echo $this->installSettings($_POST['setting']);
        } else {
            echo $this->installSettings();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Form to create setting is rendered and created.
     *
     * @param null $settings            
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function installSettings($settings = null)
    {
        if ($settings == null) {
            return $this->render('./View/Install/settings.php', '');
        } else {
            $insert = $this->db->insert('settings')->set(array(
                'title' => $settings['title'],
                'description' => $settings['description'],
                'copyright' => $settings['copyright']
            ));

            if ($insert) {
                header('Location:' . LINK_PREFIX);
            } else {
                return $this->render('./View/Install/setting.php', '');
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * If the application has no post or category created, user is forced to create one, after login.
     *
     * @param
     *            $request
     * @param
     *            $data
     */
    public function startCategoryAndPostInstaller()
    {
        $noCategories = $this->getCategories() == null;
        $noPosts = $this->getPosts() == null;
        if ($noCategories || $noPosts) {
            if (isset($_SESSION['id']) || (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']))) {
                if ((isset($_SESSION['id']) || $this->login($_POST) != false)) {
                    if ($noCategories && mb_strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) != '/' . $directoryName . '/categories/add' && mb_strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) != '/' . DIRECTORY_NAME . '/users/logout') {
                        header('Location:' . LINK_PREFIX . '/categories/add');
                    }
                    echo $this->calculate($this->request, $this->data);
                }
            } else {
                echo $this->login();
            }
        } else {
            echo $this->calculate($this->request, $this->data);
        }
    }

    /**
     * We need to check posts to redirect user to create some posts if there are not.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getPosts()
    {
        $posts = new Posts($this->db);
        return $posts->index();
    }

    /**
     * Renders login form if authorized user actions are needed
     *
     * @param null $data            
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function login($data = null)
    {
        $users = new Users($this->db);
        if ($data != null) {
            return $users->login($data['username'], $data['password']);
        } else {
            echo $this->render('./View/Install/login.php', '');
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Renders requests and handles data from visitor.
     * 
     * @return null
     */
    public function calculate()
    {
        echo new Router($this->data, $this->getCategories(), $this->settings, $this->params);
        return null;
    }
}

?>
```

Router.php:

```
    <?php
/**
 * Router class that gets requests from app and render a response.
 *
 * @author     Midori Kocak <mtkocak@mtkocak.net>
 */

namespace Midori\Cms;


/**
 * Class Router
 * @package Midori\Cms
 */
class Router
{
    /**
     * Data generated from request
     *
     * @var array|null
     */
    private $data = array();

    /**
     * Flash messages
     *
     * @var null
     */
    private $message = null;

    /**
     * If isset, template file is rendered for layout. public|admin
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $template = 'public';

    /**
     * If isset, an action can render a custom view file than it's default show|index|add|edit
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $renderFile = 'show';

    /**
     * If false response is not rendered, else default render file for action is rendered
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    private $render = false;

    /**
     * Related data is saved here. For now, application wide categories are hold here.
     * TODO Static
     *
     * @var null
     */
    private $related = null;

    /**
     * Application wide settings are here.
     * TODO Static
     *
     * @var null
     */
    private $settings = null;

    /**
     * Request parameters
     *
     * @var null
     */
    private $params = null;

    /**
     * Constructor that gets data from App class. Class, post and other data already injected here.
     *
     * @param null $classData
     * @param null $related
     * @param null $settings
     * @param null $params
     */
    public function __construct($classData = null, $related = null, $settings = null, $params = null)
    {

        if (isset($classData['template'])) {
            $this->template = $classData['template'];
        }

        if (isset($classData['renderFile'])) {
            $this->renderFile = $classData['renderFile'];
        }

        if (isset($classData['message'])) {
            $this->message = $classData['message'];
        }

        if (isset($classData['render'])) {
            $this->render = $classData['render'];
        }

        if ($related != null) {
            $this->related = $related;
        }

        if ($settings != null) {
            $this->settings = $settings;
        }

        if ($classData != null) {
            $this->data = $classData;
        }

        if ($params != null) {
            $this->params = $params;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Class is printed at App class. When class is printed, this function is called magically.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        $content = $this->createContent();
        return $this->wrapTemplate($content);
    }


    /**
     * Class actions rendered here together all variables.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function createContent()
    {
        $content = array('message' => $this->message, 'related' => $this->related, 'content' => $this->render('./View/' . $this->params[1] . '/' . mb_strtolower($this->params[2]) . '.php', $this->data));
        return $content;
    }

    /**
     * All render operations are handled here. Output buffer and include.
     *
     * @param $file
     * @param $vars
     * @return string
     */
    public function render($file, $vars)
    {
        if (is_array($vars) && !empty($vars)) {
            extract($vars);
        }

        if ($this->settings != false && !isset($title)) {
            extract($this->settings);
        }

        ob_start();
        include $file;
        return ob_get_clean();
    }

    /**
     * Context template is rendered and wrapped to class actions.
     *
     * @param $content
     * @return string
     */
    private function wrapTemplate($content)
    {
        return $this->render('./www/' . $this->template . '.php', $content);
    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your `App` class violates the Single Responsibility principle and the Open Closed Principle.

- SRP -> I think you should create different Creators for each Entity.
- OCP -> I think you should create more abstract classes in case your project gets bigger, and then create more specific instances for each feature.

I wrote [an article](http://jokiruiz.com/solid-principles-php/) about solid principles and PHP a while ago. And you may want to take a look at [design patterns](http://jokiruiz.com/php-design-patterns/). The factory method will help you on your project.

Comment: This is the only site that you don't have spam on, but _have_ posted something on, and I'm not convinced that you didn't do it by accident.

Answer (score 2):

**Security**

```
    $this->params = explode("/", $this->request);

    $params = $this->params;

    $className = __NAMESPACE__ . '\\' . $this->params[1];

    $class = new $className($this->db);
    $class->getRelatedData($this->getCategories());

    if (empty($this->data)) {
        if (! isset($params[2]) || ! $params[2]) {
            $this->params[2] = 'index';
        } else {
            if (isset($params[3])) {
                $this->data = $class->$params[2]($params[3]);
            } else {
                $this->data = $class->$params[2]();
            }
        }
    } else {
        $this->data = call_user_func_array(array(
            $class,
            $params[2]
        ), $this->data);
        header('Location:' . LINK_PREFIX . '/'.$this->params[1].'/show');
    }
```

This doesn't look all that secure. A user can create any class, and they can call any method of that class with any argument they want. This means that you give up complete control over the control flow of your application. I would be very surprised if this wouldn't lead to DOS, SQL injection, authentication bypass, probably code execution, etc.

You really need to create a whitelist of classes and methods the user is allowed to use and check against that.

```
private function createContent()
{
    $content = array('message' => $this->message, 'related' => $this->related, 'content' => $this->render('./View/' . $this->params[1] . '/' . mb_strtolower($this->params[2]) . '.php', $this->data));
    return $content;
}

public function render($file, $vars)
{
    if (is_array($vars) && !empty($vars)) {
        extract($vars);
    }

    if ($this->settings != false && !isset($title)) {
        extract($this->settings);
    }

    ob_start();
    include $file;
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

This is also in no way secure. Via the `$file` argument, an attacker can include any PHP file, which may lead to DOS or bypassing of your authentication code.

Additionally, because you call `extract` on user input, an attacker can overwrite the `$file` argument and thus gain LFI.

Also:

- `md5` isn't acceptable for password hashing. It's broken and too fast. Use bcrypt instead.
- `header` redirects do not have to be followed by the client, so you should always `die` afterwards.

**Single Responsibility**

`App` definitely does way too much. The name already hints at this: Whenever you can't think of a fitting name, you are likely in violation of single responsibility.

Your `App` class:

- is partly responsible for routing (in the constructor)
- contains the install code
- handles sessions
- parses requests
- handles the database connection
- manages categories, users, and posts
- manages settings
- handles the login

That is way too much. Each of these tasks should be happening in a designated class. You should definitely take a look at MVC, it might help you get an idea how you might want to structure your code.

Your `Router` class doesn't seem to really route anything. I would expect it to take a route such as `/user/edit/1` and call the code that is responsible to edit the user with the id 1.